# Use string length as parameter in if loop

Tags: string, google-apps-script

I am attempting to check the values in a specific Column(B).  Those values are based on a formula in the cells in Column B.  What I am wanting to do is: if the length of the resulting string is greater than 15, to copy and paste the Displayed Value in the same cell (overwriting the formula).  The formula that is there is a simple if(x>y, {do this},""{Leave cell blank}).  If possible, I'd also like to expand it for 5 consecutive columns.  The "IF" formula will be in each column.

Here is the dilemma another way.  In column 'B' I have the =if(X>Y, Z{do this},""{Leave cell blank})in each row.  If the formula result is true, copy the displayed value and overwrite the formula, if it is false, leave the formula there.

I have found this as a starting block, but it overwrites the formula regardless of the True/false outcome.

```
    function myFunction() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = s.getSheetByName('Copy');
    var range = ss.getRange('b9:b12');     //This is just a test range, the real range will be the entire column.
    var cells = range.getValues();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
     for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {      
       if(cells.length > 15){
         cells[i][j] ;
      }
     }
    }

   range.setValues(cells);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function usingstringlength() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = s.getSheetByName('Copy');
  var range = ss.getRange('b9:b12');
  var vs = range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vs[i].length;j++) {      
      if(vs[i][j].toString().length > 15){
        vs[i][j]+="I am greater than 15";
      }
    }
  }  
  range.setValues(vs);
}



function usingstringlength() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = s.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var vs = range.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vs[i].length;j++) {      
      if(vs[i][j].toString().length > 15){
       ss.getRange(i+1,j+1).setValue("Whatever I'm not sure")
      }
    }
  }  
  range.setValues(vs);
}
```

Data Before Running:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8
16,11,17,11,12,15,4,17
14,17,14,14,4,11,13,11
9,9,10,11,14,10,5,9
10,3,11,17,10,8,6,8
5,12,13,18,7,9,2,15
2,5,10,9,18,18,12,12
15,1,11,11,7,1,4,4
6,1,0,7,2,17,11,11
18,9,9,6,15,9,0,10
15,2,1,14,16,4,19,15
14,5,11,14,2,17,10,1
19,4,19,5,5,1,15,7
9,5,15,12,8,3,9,11
11,12,2,0,4,13,8,2
13,17,5,18,13,16,19,5
15,18,16,0,8,19,18,4
16,19,6,0,4,3,9,11
12,6,6,12,18,5,1,2
2,19,10,4,13,14,6,1
6,10,15,8,12,8,3,5
```

Data After Running:

```
COL1I am greater than 1,COL2I am greater than 1,COL3I am greater than 1,COL4I am greater than 1,COL5I am greater than 1,COL6I am greater than 1,COL7I am greater than 1,COL8I am greater than 1
16I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1,17I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1,12I am greater than 1,15I am greater than 1,4,17I am greater than 1
14I am greater than 1,17I am greater than 1,14I am greater than 1,14I am greater than 1,4,11I am greater than 1,13I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1
9,9,10I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1,14I am greater than 1,10I am greater than 1,5,9
10I am greater than 1,3,11I am greater than 1,17I am greater than 1,10I am greater than 1,8,6,8
5,12I am greater than 1,13I am greater than 1,18I am greater than 1,7,9,2,15I am greater than 1
2,5,10I am greater than 1,9,18I am greater than 1,18I am greater than 1,12I am greater than 1,12I am greater than 1
15I am greater than 1,1,11I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1,7,1,4,4
6,1,0,7,2,17I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1,11I am greater than 1
18I am greater than 1,9,9,6,15I am greater than 1,9,0,10I am greater than 1
15I am greater than 1,2,1,14I am greater than 1,16I am greater than 1,4,19I am greater than 1,15I am greater than 1
14I am greater than 1,5,11I am greater than 1,14I am greater than 1,2,17I am greater than 1,10I am greater than 1,1
19I am greater than 1,4,19I am greater than 1,5,5,1,15I am greater than 1,7
9,5,15I am greater than 1,12I am greater than 1,8,3,9,11I am greater than 1
11I am greater than 1,12I am greater than 1,2,0,4,13I am greater than 1,8,2
13I am greater than 1,17I am greater than 1,5,18I am greater than 1,13I am greater than 1,16I am greater than 1,19I am greater than 1,5
15I am greater than 1,18I am greater than 1,16I am greater than 1,0,8,19I am greater than 1,18I am greater than 1,4
16I am greater than 1,19I am greater than 1,6,0,4,3,9,11I am greater than 1
12I am greater than 1,6,6,12I am greater than 1,18I am greater than 1,5,1,2
2,19I am greater than 1,10I am greater than 1,4,13I am greater than 1,14I am greater than 1,6,1
6,10I am greater than 1,15I am greater than 1,8,12I am greater than 1,8,3,5
```

Comment: As always, I appreciate your help @Cooper.  However, it is still overwriting the formulas.  I think it has to do with the .toString().  The formula I will need in the finished product is over 100 characters, so when it converts the formula to a string, it overwrites it.  I am only wanting to overwrite the Formula with the Display Value if the Display Value is greater than X. (X being 15 for my test, but will be about 22 in the final)

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the issue.  When calling **range.setValues(vs)**...It is setting the value of "vs" before the filter of checking whether the string length is greater than 15. Any ideas @Cooper

Comment: I saw this part ` if(cells.length > 15){
         cells[i][j] ;
      }` but it doesn't do anything so I didn't know what you wanted?  What is it that you are trying to accomplish there?

Comment: In the final version, I will have a large table of data.  One of the columns, (R) has a formula which if today's date is greater than a certain date, uses the  **join** formula to merge the data from  several columns into one, if it has not reached that date threshold, the cell is blank. Once the date threshold is reached, and the cell displays X|Y|Z|etc...I want to copy that cells display value, and paste it over the formula.

Comment: Well that's probably your answer.

Comment: I apologize, but I am still not understanding what the answer is.  Essentially, I need to script this.  **=if(len(R25)>22, {COPY R25, then paste value or R25 into R25}," " {Leave cell blank}

Comment: Possibly...But I don't use cell functions so I can't help you there.

Comment: How could I adapt the previously submitted script to only set the values of those in the array that fit the .length>15 criteria?  Leaving the rest untouched?

Comment: You will have to use setValue() for each row